# AngularJs ngRepeat from n to m

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make a blog and I'm using angularJs.
I have all articles in a Json File which is made like this

articles.json

```
  {
        "title": "Post One",
        "body": [
          "First paragraph", 
          "Second paragraph",
          "..."
        ],
        "author": "Author",
        "comments": [
          {
            "body":"Comment no 1",
            "author": "AuthorComment"
          }
        ],
        "likes":0,
        "createdOn": today-date
  },
```

now, into my HTML I would like to display the newest article on top and, into another div, I would like to put 6 more articles from newest to oldest (so it means articles from 2 to 7).

Something like this:

```
<div id="newest-article" ng-repeat="post in posts|limitTo:1">
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>
</div>

<div id="list-of-six-posts">
<h1>Post 2</h1>
</p>Body post 2</p>
<h1>Post 3</h1>
</p>Body post 3</p>
<h1>Post 4</h1>
</p>Body post 4</p>
<h1>Post 5</h1>
</p>Body post 5</p>
<h1>Post 6</h1>
</p>Body post 6</p>
<h1>Post 7</h1>
</p>Body post 7</p>
</div>
```

**Question is**: how can I use ng-repeat to say "repeat from post 2 to post 7"?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the answer by myself.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in blog.posts" ng-if="$index >=1 && $index<7">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dear**,

You could do it Like this :

```
<div id="newest-article" ng-repeat="post in posts|limitTo:1">
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>
</div>

<div id="rest-article" ng-if="$index > 0 ng-repeat="post in posts">
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<p>{{post.body}}</p>
</div>
```

This will skip the index 0 means your values would be printing on screen from index 1 only.

**Thanks & Cheers**